# How to Sent selected value DropDownList from View Razor to controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this in the `HTTPGET` Controller

```
SelectList ConvenioList = Utilidades.ObtenerConveniosList();
ViewData["ConveniosList"] = ConvenioList;
return View();
```

In the Razor View I have theses code for represent the list in `DropDownList` Like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ConveniosList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ConveniosList"], new { @class = "form-control pull-right", @id = "ConvenioId", @style = "color:black;" })
```

And then The List show it like this in the screen:

DropDownList With Data

[image]

I want when a selected one item and summit search button Get the value select in the controller POST like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Transactions (string rangofecha, [<selected list value>] , string referencia)
  { //do soothing with the values received  }
```

Comment: `public ActionResult Transactions (string rangofecha, string ConveniosList , string referencia)` ought to do it. The selected value is just a single variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your View you have this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ConveniosList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ConveniosList"], new { @class = "form-control pull-right", @id = "ConvenioId", @style = "color:black;" })
```

In MVC, model binding is dependent on the name of the element.. and in your case, the name of the dropdownlist is `ConveniosList` (the first parameter in the DropDownList overload).

So in your controller, where you are binding the values with your action, you need to include the name of the dropdownlist in your parameters like so:

```
public ActionResult Transactions (string rangofecha, /*[<selected list value>]*/string ConveniosList , string referencia)
```

The reason why you have to declare `ConveniosList` as a string is because when you select a value from a dropdownlist.. the value is sent to the controller.. and the value is of type string.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Excellent Brother, That was simpler that I Have thought. Thank you so much.

Comment: OP has not shown the code for generating the SelectList, but the option values might be `int` in which case it should be `int ConveniosList` (not `string`)